# Unresolved plugin: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0'

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-plugin, distributed-computing

I tried to set up Maven projects under my IntelliJ IDE. However, when I try to update the pom.xml file, I am getting this error. I tried deleting the .m2 repository under Users, made the changes under Build Tools for Maven. Still, the issue doesn't seem to get resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try
File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart
so IntelliJ will try index again to the resources.

Comment: Are you able to answer this question by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104529/can-maven-run-both-cucumber-junit-and-testng-runners-together

Comment: I tried that too, but still no luck.

Comment: When you try mvn clean install the build is successful or not? I'm trying to see if it's an IntelliJ problem or an actual maven problem because of a jar that does not exist in the m2 repo.

Comment: Actually, mvn command is not working only. It shows the 'command not found' error.

Comment: I figured out why it went wrong. Apparently, the maven-version folder hadn't been configured to PATH variable on the System Variables.

Comment: So IntelliJ could not use mvn to install the dependencies because maven was not configured as system variable.